# How to handle slow server replies when checking a large number of feeds?

Tags: php, rss

I need to check a couple of hundred RSS/Atom feeds with PHP and update a MySQL database, if there is a new item. The script is run by the cron deamon at certain intervals.

The problem I encounter is that many of the servers hosting the feeds are very slow to reply, so I have tried to increase the timeout for my PHP script, but the result is that now the script is sometimes running several minutes, which I understand is not ideal, and it still stops processing eventually and doesn't finish all feeds.

I know that not all feeds are finished, because the last entries in the database never get updated, even if the feeds are. I don't get an error mailed to me, but check this manually by looking at feeds and looking at the database.

What is the best (or a good) practice to handle this problem?

Comment: Do you get an error message or warning message when the script times out or terminates?

Comment: You can let scripts run as long as you like, but if they take more than a few seconds they're not suited for the front-end (serving web pages). In that case, run them as a background process or a cron job.

Comment: How are you checking now? Manually using curl or using some toolkit?

Comment: @Kenney The script is run by a cronjob.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The script runs as a cronjob. I see that it does not finish because only the first database rows get updated.

Comment: @thebestusernameever I'm not sure. No errors are mailed to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run it from terminal
2. Treat every feed as it is own job/task
3. Make sure that those  job/tasks do not block each other.
4. To achieve (3) run your PHP script in multiple threads/processes (one for each feed)

   1. Use queuing system to manage jobs (ZeroMQ, RabbitMq, Gearman ...)
   2. Use PHP or it libs to manage jobs (
      http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php,
      http://reactphp.org/)
   3. Or use Queuing system and PHP tools.

So in the end you would have a PHP script/worker that can only grab and process one feed at a time. And something that tells it what feed to grab.

This way you would know which feeds failed or take too long without blocking rest of them.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines. Sorry for not mentioning that the script is run as a cronjob. So I was thinking to have one cronjob for each feed, but that would mean lots of cronjobs, and I would have to update the crontab every time I added a new feed to the database.

Comment: One cronjob that submits all jobs in a queue (all at once). Multiple workers that process things from queue one by one. So it is going to be just one cronjob and as many work daemons as you need.

Comment: Did similar system on Zend_Queue, Gearman, RabbitMQ, all of them have own problems but all work

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not familiar with this and need to check it out.